# How to select parallel edges

Tags: edges, select

As in the title - how do I select edges that are parallel to the edge or edges that I preselected?

I don't mean selecting edge loops or rings. My mesh is triangulated, so I don't have any of them. I need to select edges that are mathematically parallel in model space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shift G, select similar, direction.

Comment: Yup, that works. Thank you!